# Python: Is original source code viewable when converting a python script to .exe file using py2exe?

Tags: python, text, exe, py2exe

I made a python script that saves its output into a .text file. The .text file contents is scrambled but the python script I made can unscramble the text. If I use py2exe to make the script an .exe file, will others be able to see the script it uses to unscramble the text if they have a copy of the .exe file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Py2Exe packages your script with a standalone Python interpreter, but under normal circumstances won't "compile" it.

Viewing the source code for a Py2Exe package executable would be trivial.